# Unable to update on Ubuntu 14.04lts

Tags: 14.04

I recently upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Everything was fine until now, whenever I try to update or install software via terminal I get this message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I have no idea what other process could be running on background . Please help I am not enjoying my new O.S. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` in terminal which will remove the lock file created by any of the dpkg applications(like synaptic, ubuntu-software-center etc.). Then do `sudo apt-get update`.